# Como personalizar checkbox/radio sem usar background: url?

Tags: css, checkbox, radiobutton

Sempre que pesquiso sobre "personalizar", "checkboxes" e "radios", aparecem exemplos usando `background:url(image.png)`.

Há uma forma de personalizar um "checkbox" somente com "CSS" **sem** usar `background:url`?

Comment: Porque não usar uma url no background? Bom, você pode tentar com box-shadow e outros elementos internos então, bem explicados nesse  [artigo](http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/custom-form-radio-checkbox/)

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava, o `-webkit-appearance: none;` meio que "reseta" as propriedades do checkbox para poder personalizar. Responda com isso que atribuo como certa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar usar o `-webkit-appearance: none;` para resetar o estilo padrão e personalizar o radio e outros elementos de input, como bem explicado [nesse artigo](http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/custom-form-radio-checkbox/).